# Display zone in opencart billing instead of zone_code

Tags: php, opencart

Instead of the zone name all I'm receiving is zone_code. I have added a snapshot of my bill generated below.

If you look below the "To" field and "Ship to" field are displaying zone_code instead of the zone name. How do I fix this issue. Which files should I be looking into?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your var zone_code not changed by the data from oc_order table in admin/controller/sale/order.php or may be it wasn't filled by customer during order.
Attach this file to look what the problem could be. (If you not modified this dil by vqmod. If you had modified attach vqmoded file)